# Proof Vectors are coplanar

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, $\vec v_3$ be three vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$. We say these vectors are coplanar, if there is a plane through the origin in $\mathbb{R^3}$ that contains all of them.

Show that $\vec v_1$, $\vec v_2$, $\vec v_3$ are coplanar if and only if they are linearly independent?

I started by using the definition of linear independence (e.g coefficients equal to zero) but I am somewhat confused how to set up this proof.

Comment: Should it be coplanar if and only if linearly dependent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you meant  coplanar if and only if they are linearly dependent because otherwise it is false.

If $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}$ are coplanar, their triple product $\mathbf{u} \cdot (\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w})$ is $0$ since $\mathbf{u}$ must be perpendicular to $\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{w}$.
The triple product can be calculated using the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
u_0 && u_1 && u_2 \\
v_0 && v_1 && v_2 \\
w_0 && w_1 && w_2
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
A determinant of $0$ implies that the rows are linearly dependent. This proof is bi-directional.

If you don't want to use determinant, you can instead use the fact that a plane is a $2$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and since $\{\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\}$ is a list of $3 > 2$ elements, it is linearly dependent.

For the other direction, if $\{\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}, \mathbf{w}\}$ is linearly dependent, then one of the vectors(without loss of generality we can assume to be $\mathbf{w}$) is a linear combination of two others. That is, $\lambda\mathbf{u} + \mu\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{w}$. The span of this set is hence equal to the span of $\{\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}\}$, a plane.